# PHP copy on write process

Tags: php

It is said that PHP uses copy-on-write processes. Then I wander if I run these codes:

```
$first = 5;
$second = $first;
$first = 5;
```

Then does it allocate new memory space for **$first**? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

run this script twice.
first time:

```
echo "<pre>";
$first = 5;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
$second = $first;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
$first = 5;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

result:

```
333224
333280
333312
```

second time - just comment one line

```
echo "<pre>";
$first = 5;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
//$second = $first;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
$first = 5;
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

result:

```
333112
333112
333112
```

answer: yes, it allocates new memory

Answer (score 0):

The semantic is "copy-on-write" NOT "copy-on-write-only-if-the-value-has-changed".

Also some space for $second is created as soon you declare it. The minimal space required for that variable to exist. At this time the space is NOT allocated for the value that the $first has. So copy on write is at work here; there is no write so no extra space allocated for the value allocated to $first, which is now being assigned to $second.

Then further space is allocated to $second the moment you assign something else to $first. At that time the space is created to hold the copy of the original value in $first

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    // 10 sets == 100 chars
    $first = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    $second = $first;
    echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    $first = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    $first = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

Output

```
241496
241584
241752
241752
```